# tls-websocket connection fails "http: TLS handshake error from [...] : remote error: tls: unknown certificate"

Tags: go, nginx, ssl, websocket, gorilla

My problem is that my websocket connection fails everytime when a client (a svelte/node.js application running on a NGINX webserver) connects to my server.

###### Golang/Gorilla Server:

```golang
func (s Server) Init() {
    s.Sessions = make(map[string]*Session)
    go http.HandleFunc("/", s.handler)
    err := http.ListenAndServeTLS(":4000", "tls/cert.pem","tls/key.pem" , nil)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}
```

"err" outputs: `http: TLS handshake error from [...] : remote error: tls: unknown certificate`

I'm using the same certificate that I created with letsencrypt on my NGINX webserver, that is used for a tls connection between webserver and browser.
I believe it has something to do with my non-existent knowledge about tls certifcates.

Thank you in advance!

### NGINX config

```
server {

        root /home/ubuntu/actions-runner/_work/client/client/public;

        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name myserver.io www.myserver.io; # managed by Certbot


        location / {
                proxy_http_version 1.1; # FOR WEBSOCKET PROTOCOL 
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; # FOR WEBSOCKET PROTOCOL 
                proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade"; # FOR WEBSOCKET PROTOCOL

                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.io/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver.io/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot



}server {
    if ($host = www.myserver.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = myserver.io) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name myserver.io www.myserver.io;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

Comment: Also I just discovered that, when I'm using my phone (Safari Browser) the output says: `TLS handshake error from [...] : EOF`